# Keras: custom loss causes "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a variational autoencoder in Keras following the [example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py) in the Keras repository. Here's my setup:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, merge, concatenate, Dense, LSTM, Lambda, Flatten, Reshape
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from keras.losses import mse
import numpy as np

class VAE:
  def __init__(self, n_verts=15, n_dims=3, n_layers=3, n_units=128, latent_dim=2):
    self.n_verts = n_verts
    self.n_dims = n_dims
    self.n_layers = n_layers
    self.n_units = n_units
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim
    self.encoder = self.build_encoder()
    self.decoder = self.build_decoder()
    inputs = Input((self.n_verts, self.n_dims))
    outputs = self.decoder(self.encoder(inputs)[2])
    self.model = Model(inputs, outputs, name='vae')
    self.model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=self.get_loss)

  def build_encoder(self):
    i = Input(shape=(self.n_verts, self.n_dims), name='encoder_input')
    h = i
    h = Flatten()(h)
    h = Dense(self.n_units, activation='relu')(h)
    for idx in range(1, self.n_layers, 1):
      h = Dense(self.n_units // (2*idx), activation='relu')(h)
    self.z_mean = Dense(self.latent_dim, name='z_mean')(h)
    self.z_log_var = Dense(self.latent_dim, name='z_log_var')(h)
    # use reparameterization trick to factor stochastic node out of gradient flow
    self.z = Lambda(self.sample, output_shape=(self.latent_dim,), name='z')([self.z_mean, self.z_log_var])
    return Model(i, [self.z_mean, self.z_log_var, self.z], name='encoder')

  def sample(self, args):
    '''
    Reparameterization trick by sampling from an isotropic unit Gaussian.
      @arg (tensor): mean and log of variance of Q(z|X)
      @returns z (tensor): sampled latent vector
    '''
    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    batch = K.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim = K.int_shape(z_mean)[1]
    # by default, random_normal has mean = 0 and std = 1.0
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
    return z_mean + K.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon

  def build_decoder(self):
    i = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,), name='z_sampling')
    h = i
    for idx in range(1, self.n_layers, 1):
      h = Dense(self.n_units//(2*(self.n_layers-idx)), activation='relu')(h)
    h = Dense(self.n_units, activation='relu')(h)
    h = Dense(self.n_verts * self.n_dims, activation='sigmoid')(h)
    o = Reshape((self.n_verts, self.n_dims))(h)
    return Model(i, o, name='decoder')

  def get_loss(self, inputs, outputs):
    reconstruction_loss = mse(inputs, outputs)
    reconstruction_loss *= self.n_verts * self.n_dims
    return reconstruction_loss # this works fine
    kl_loss = 1 + self.z_log_var - K.square(self.z_mean) - K.exp(self.z_log_var)
    kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
    kl_loss *= -0.5
    vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss) # todo: make this balance parameterizable
    return vae_loss # this doesn't

  def train(self, X, predict='frame', n_epochs=10000):
    for idx in range(n_epochs):
      i = np.random.randint(0, X.shape[1]-1) # sample idx
      frame = np.expand_dims( X[:,i:i+1,:].squeeze(), axis=0) # shape = 1 sample, v verts, d dims
      next_frame = np.expand_dims( X[:,i+1:i+2,:].squeeze(), axis=0)
      if predict == 'frame': loss = self.model.train_on_batch(frame, frame)
      elif predict == 'next_frame': loss = self.model.train_on_batch(frame, next_frame)
      if idx % 1000 == 0:
        print(' * training idx', idx, 'loss', loss)

X_train = np.random.rand(15, 100, 3)
vae = VAE(n_verts=15, latent_dim=2, n_layers=3, n_units=128)
vae.encoder.summary()
vae.train(X_train, n_epochs=10000, predict='frame')
```

This works, but if you look at the `get_loss` function you'll see it's returning a little prematurely. If I comment out `return reconstruction_loss` so that the loss function returns `vae_loss`, I get an error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-7-57d76ed539a4> in <module>
     78 vae = VAE(n_verts=15, latent_dim=2, n_layers=3, n_units=128)
     79 vae.encoder.summary()
---> 80 vae.train(X_train, n_epochs=10000, predict='frame')

<ipython-input-7-57d76ed539a4> in train(self, X, predict, n_epochs)
     70       frame = np.expand_dims( X[:,i:i+1,:].squeeze(), axis=0) # shape = 1 sample, v verts, d dims
     71       next_frame = np.expand_dims( X[:,i+1:i+2,:].squeeze(), axis=0)
---> 72       if predict == 'frame': loss = self.model.train_on_batch(frame, frame)
     73       elif predict == 'next_frame': loss = self.model.train_on_batch(frame, next_frame)
     74       if idx % 1000 == 0:

~/anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight)    1215     ins = x + y + sample_weights    1216         self._make_train_function()
-> 1217         outputs = self.train_function(ins)    1218         return unpack_singleton(outputs)    1219 

~/anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)    2713                 return self._legacy_call(inputs)    2714 
-> 2715             return self._call(inputs)    2716         else:    2717             if py_any(is_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

~/anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in _call(self, inputs)    2673             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals, run_metadata=self.run_metadata)    2674 else:
-> 2675             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)    2676         return fetched[:len(self.outputs)]    2677 

~/anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)    1437           ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(    1438               self._session._session, self._handle, args, status,
-> 1439               run_metadata_ptr)    1440         if run_metadata:    1441           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~/anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    526             None, None,
    527             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 528             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    530     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'encoder_input_6' with dtype float and shape [?,15,3]     [[{{node encoder_input_6}}]]
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this error? Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I got this worked out once my variables were scoped properly:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, merge, concatenate, Dense, LSTM, Lambda, Flatten, Reshape
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from keras.losses import mse
import numpy as np


class VAE:
  def __init__(self, n_verts=15, n_dims=3, n_layers=3, n_units=128, latent_dim=2):
    self.input_shape = (n_verts*n_dims,)
    self.n_layers = n_layers
    self.n_units = n_units
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim
    # build the encoder and decoder
    inputs = Input(shape=self.input_shape, name='encoder_input')
    self.encoder = self.get_encoder(inputs)
    self.decoder = self.get_decoder()
    # build the VAE
    outputs = self.decoder(self.encoder(inputs)[2])
    self.model = Model(inputs, outputs, name='vae_mlp')
    # add loss and compile
    self.model.add_loss(self.get_loss(inputs, outputs))
    self.model.compile(optimizer='adam')


  def get_encoder(self, inputs):
    h = inputs
    h = Dense(self.n_units, activation='relu')(h)
    for idx in range(1, self.n_layers, 1):
      h = Dense(self.n_units // (2*idx), activation='relu')(h)
    self.z_mean = Dense(self.latent_dim, name='z_mean')(h)
    self.z_log_var = Dense(self.latent_dim, name='z_log_var')(h)
    z = Lambda(self.sampling, output_shape=(self.latent_dim,), name='z')([self.z_mean, self.z_log_var])
    encoder = Model(inputs, [self.z_mean, self.z_log_var, z], name='encoder')
    return encoder


  def sampling(self, args):
    self.z_mean, self.z_log_var = args
    batch = K.shape(self.z_mean)[0]
    dim = K.int_shape(self.z_mean)[1]
    # by default, random_normal has mean = 0 and std = 1.0
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
    return self.z_mean + K.exp(0.5 * self.z_log_var) * epsilon


  def get_decoder(self):
    latent_inputs = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,), name='z_sampling')
    h = latent_inputs
    for idx in range(1, self.n_layers, 1):
      h = Dense(self.n_units//(2*(self.n_layers-idx)), activation='relu')(h)
    h = Dense(self.n_units, activation='relu')(h)
    outputs = Dense(self.input_shape[0], activation='sigmoid')(h)
    decoder = Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')
    return decoder


  def get_loss(self, inputs, outputs):
    reconstruction_loss = mse(inputs, outputs)
    reconstruction_loss *= self.input_shape[0]
    kl_loss = 1 + self.z_log_var - K.square(self.z_mean) - K.exp(self.z_log_var)
    kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
    kl_loss *= -0.5
    vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
    return vae_loss


# train
x_train = np.random.rand(10000, 45)
vae = VAE(n_verts=15, latent_dim=2, n_layers=3, n_units=128)
vae.model.fit(x_train[:-1000,:],
        epochs=100,
        batch_size=128,
        validation_data=(x_train[-1000:,:], None))
```